# Wordpress/Woocommerce - Editing word before product price only in certain categories

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm wanting to add the word "From" before the price of woocommerce products only in certain categories. I've messed around with some code snippets but cant seems to get it working.

Example
Products within category 1 and 2 will display "From $X.XX"
And products within any other category with display the normal "$X.XX"

I would also like to add a line of text below every product price.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click and inspect the product area you will see a bunch of classes to target the category you want.

then just use

```
.product_cat-categoryname .price:before {
    content: "\From ";
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: That's worked great thanks! Could you recommend a way to add a line of code/text below every product price?

Comment: just use `:after` instead of `:before`

glad I could help :)